# Changing a number into zero in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following matrix:

```
a = array([
   [100. , 100., 100.],
   [175.2, 198.,  32.],
   [ 38. , 82. ,  38.],
   [155. , 32. ,  23.],
   [ 38. , 67. ,  30.]])
```

How do I change the numbers in all rows, but except the last row into zero if a number of a row is not equal to 38 and 32? What I want to get is as follows:

```
a = array([
   [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ],
   [ 0 ,  0 , 32.],
   [38.,  0 , 38.],
   [ 0 , 32.,  0 ],
   [38., 67., 30.]])
```

And then I want to leave just the earliest number that appears in each column. Something like this:

```
a = array([
   [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ],
   [ 0 ,  0 , 32.],
   [38.,  0 ,  0 ],
   [ 0 , 32.,  0 ],
   [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ]])
```

Comment: What did you try to do? Post your attempt to modify the array, and we can then help you figure out what you're doing wrong

Comment: Nitpick: that's an array, not a matrix. It's an important distinction in general because NumPy _does_ have a `matrix` type, that's distinct from (but inherits from) the `ndarray` array type.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I tried to use this comment a[np.any(a != 38, axis=1)] = 0, but what it gives is that it changes everything into zero and I dont know how to impose - "change into zero the numbers in all rows except the last one if the number is not equal to 38 or 32"

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
positions = [(y, x) for x, y in enumerate(np.argmax(np.isin(a, [32,38]), axis=0))]

result = np.zeros(a.shape)

for p in positions:
    result[p] = a[p]

#[[ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ],
# [ 0 ,  0 , 32.],
# [38.,  0 ,  0 ],
# [ 0 , 32.,  0 ],
# [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorised and in place solution.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[100. , 100., 100.],
              [175.2, 198.,  32.],
              [ 38. , 82. ,  38.],
              [155. , 32. ,  23.],
              [ 38. , 67. ,  30.]])

a[:-1][(a[:-1]!=38) & (a[:-1]!=32)] = 0

# array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
#        [  0.,   0.,  32.],
#        [ 38.,   0.,  38.],
#        [  0.,  32.,   0.],
#        [ 38.,  67.,  30.]])
```

You can also use `numpy` for your final result:

```
idx = ((a!=0).argmax(axis=0), np.array(range(a.shape[1])))
result = np.empty(a.shape)
result[idx] = a[idx]

# array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
#        [  0.,   0.,  32.],
#        [ 38.,   0.,   0.],
#        [  0.,  32.,   0.],
#        [  0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more (albeit inefficient) solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
   [100. , 100., 100.],
   [175.2, 198.,  32.],
   [ 38. , 82. ,  38.],
   [155. , 32. ,  23.],
   [ 38. , 67. ,  30.]])


def what(y,lastRow):
    found = False
    for o in y:
        if o in [32,38] and not found and not lastRow:
            found = True
            yield o
        else:
            yield 0

# probably inefficient due to list comp instead of np-own ops
b = np.array([list(what(y,idy==len(a)-1)) for idy,y in enumerate(a)]) 

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  32.]
 [ 38.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  32.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]]
```